# What is the magnitude of the Hunting Horn's buffs?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In Monster Hunter World, various attack and affinity boosts from different sources have undergone balancing so attack is not always preferable to affinity. With that said, it's unlikely that the Hunting Horn's melodies have gone untouched, but I can't find any numbers on the matter.

How large are the various buffs that a Hunting Horn's melodies can provide? Specifically, I'm asking about Attack Up (S/L/XL), Defense Up (S/L/XL), Affinity Up (S/L), Elemental Attack Boost (S/L), and Abnormal Status Attack Increased (S/L).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the results of some testing:

- Attack Up (S/L/XL) increases attack by 10/15/20% of the weapon's base attack respectively.
- Defense Up (S/L/XL) increases defense by 10/15/20% of base defense respectively.
- Affinity Up (S/L) increases affinity by 15/20% respectively.
- Elemental Attack Boost (S/L) increases elemental values by 10/15%, respectively.
- Abnormal Status Attack Up (S/L) increases status values by 10/15%, respectively.